xCoba Change the components of the metric
DefScalarFunction /@ {f, bb};
metric = DiagonalMatrix[{-f[r[]], bb[r[]], r[]^2, r[]^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2}];
metric // MatrixForm


The components of the metric take the above form.
MetricInBasis[g, -RW, metric]
MetricCompute[g, RW, "Einstein"[-1, -1]]
EinsteinCD[{1, -RW}, {1, -RW}] // ToValues


This is the $G_{11}$ component of the Einstein tensor.
metric1 = DiagonalMatrix[{-h[r[]], 1/h[r[]], r[]^2, r[]^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2}];
metric1 // MatrixForm


I have used the function h[r] to express the new components of the metric,
and I want to calculate the Einstein tensor using these new components.
MetricInBasis[g, -RW, metric1]
MetricCompute[g, RW, "Einstein"[-1, -1]]
EinsteinCD[{1, -RW}, {1, -RW}] // ToValues

However, the output still takes the form of the second picture.
How to use xCoba to change the components of a metric and calculate the new curvature tensors?

It will workfor any components, like o,1,2,3


Please include the actual Mathematica code instead of an image of the code.

I am new in this plate form and don't know how, code is posted, i have post code but dont know, where has gone.

Could please explain the difference in your code? Why did you use 'Block'?
